# Understanding Induction for Proving Inequalities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, induction

I'm trying to understand the concept of proving inequalities using induction. I know that the idea is to just create a stream of equalities/inequalities until you reach the desired expression, but I don't know if the ones I used are logically allowed.

Here is the problem I am currently working on:

Prove that $2^n > n^3$ for every integer $n \geq 10$.

**Proof:**

Define $P(n): 2^n > n^3$.

Base case $(n=10)$: Notice $2^{10} = 1,024$ and $10^3 = 1,000$. As $1,024 > 1,000$ so $P(10)$ holds.

Inductive step: Assume $P(k)$ for some $k \geq 10$. So $2^k > k^3$.

Observe $2^{k+1} = 2^{k} \cdot 2 > 2k^3$ (as $k+1 \geq 11$)

= $k^3 + k^3$

$\geq k^3 +5k^2$ (as $k \geq 10$)

$= k^3 +3k^2 + 2k^2$

$\geq k^3 + 3k^2 + 4k$

$\geq k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 = (k+1)^3$

So $P(k+1)$ holds.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh, sorry. I just wanted to know if my proof is valid.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Awesome! Thank you!